# Argument passed to an exception in the except statement of python raises TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror, try-except

I tried to run the following code

```
try:
    number = input("Enter a number ")
    print(5/int(number))
except ZeroDivisionError("No Zero") as e1:
    print('The number cannot be zero ',e1)
except ValueError as e2:
    print("The entered character is not a number ",e2)
except Exception as e: # This is a generic exception statement
    print("Some unknown exception occurred ",e)
finally: # Always executes
    print("This statement will always execute irrespective of exception is raised or not")
```

The following error was raised

```
Enter a number 0
This statement will always execute irrespective of exception is raised or not
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-32893f7d08e1> in <module>
      3     number = input("Enter a number ")
----> 4     print(5/int(number))
      5 except ZeroDivisionError("No Zero") as e1:

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-32893f7d08e1> in <module>
      3     number = input("Enter a number ")
      4     print(5/int(number))
----> 5 except ZeroDivisionError("No Zero") as e1:
      6     print('The number cannot be zero ',e1)
      7 except ValueError as e2:

TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

I am unable to understand why adding a argument to the error raises a TypeError

Comment: This is not the way to handle errors. What do you expect ths argument you add to do?

Comment: But we can add such arguments while raising the error.

Comment: Where have you seen documentation to pass arguments in that way? I am only aware of passing an argument when raising the error. I could be wrong, but some documentation might help us understand why it works that way.

Comment: It works that way because `Exception`s are an object just like any other. When raising an Exception, i.e. `ValueError("That's a ValueError")` you create **an instance of that Exception** - just like any other class. The `except` expects a **class** - as in a `type`, but you give it an instance of an Exception - which is not a class that inherits from `BaseException`

Comment: That makes sense ! Thank you @Tomerikoo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 throwing error for exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013431/python-3-throwing-error-for-exception-handling)